# my hiding div inside php not working

Tags: php, html, css, hide

```
.dq {
  display: none;
}

#s:hover~ .dq {
  display:block;
}
```

I have this code in PHP:

```
echo "
  <div class='span3 tiny'>
    <div class='pricing-table-header-tiny'>
      <h2>" . $row['Question'] . "</h2>  
    </div>
    <div class='dq'>
      <div class='pricing-table-features'>
        <p>" . $row['Answer'] . "</p>
      </div>
      <div class='Dass'>
        <p id='Dassp'>Answered by:" . $row['Doctor'] . "<p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id='s'>Show answer</a>
  </div>";
}
```

Some of them come from my sql table. What I want to achieve is when I click the show answer I want the answer to be shown. Which is hidden by default using css.
Given most above is the css snipet. Any idea what's wrong and how can I achieve this?

Comment: you are trying to select a sibling `.dq` that is coming before `#s`. this cannot be achieved, sibling selectors only work for siblings that come afterwards. If you want to use only CSS then you will have to move Show answer anchor to before `dq` element. otherwise you can use jQuery

Comment: Personally I would just use ajax to fetch the answer, or otherwise they can just view the page source if they want to see an answer to a question. Otherwise, you can always use jquery to easily show/hide elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `a` tag above the `.dq` class. that way the `sibling selector` will work.

```css
.dq {
  display: none;
}
#s:hover~ .dq {
  display: block;
}
#s {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='span3 tiny'>
  <div class='pricing-table-header-tiny'>
    <h2>" Question : whats is the question ?"</h2>


  </div>
  <a id='s'>Show answer</a>
  <div class='dq'>
    <div class='pricing-table-features'>
      <p>" Hi this is the answer "</p>
    </div>
    <div class='Dass'>
      <p id='Dassp'>Answered by: "Kim"
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**For active state //**

You have to make the `a` tag a `link` to make this work on '`:active` state.

```
<a href="" id="s">
```

and write the style for `:focus` state also

```
#s:active~ .dq,  #s:focus~ .dq{
      display: block;
    }
```

```css
.dq {
  display: none;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
 }
#s:active~ .dq,  #s:focus~ .dq{
  display: block;
}
#s {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='span3 tiny'>
  <div class='pricing-table-header-tiny'>
    <h2>" Question : whats is the question ?"</h2>


  </div>
  <a id='s' href="#">Show answer</a>
  <div class='dq'>
    <div class='pricing-table-features'>
      <p>" Hi this is the answer "</p>
    </div>
    <div class='Dass'>
      <p id='Dassp'>Answered by: "Kim"
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks that fixes it :) but i changed hover to active now.  now when i click it shows but doesn't  stay that way when i leave the click. anyway  to overcome?

Comment: @MohamedAthif I have updated the snippet. Please check :)

Comment: @MohamedAthif : See my answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735775/css-active-on-html-inside-php-echo-doesnt-stay-when-click-is-left/34736058#34736058

Answer (score 1):

> what i want to achieve is when i click the show answer i want the
>   answer to be shown.

Well you're going about it the wrong way. Your css is trying to work on hover and the html structure is wrong anyway, as pointed out by @jinu-kurian.

If you want it to work when the user clicks "show answer" you can use this method:

- add a href to the link `href="#answer"`
- add an id to the answer div `id="answer"`
- then add this css:

  #answer {   display: none; }    #answer:target {   display: block; }