# css active on html inside php echo doesn't stay when click is left

Tags: php, html, css

below is an  echo in a php file which also uses sql to get data. answer is hidden by default using css  display: none. but when the show answer is clicked it shows. my problem is that the answer doesnt stay shown when the click is left. like when i click it shows but doesnt stay when i leave the click. how do i make it stay?

```
echo "<div class='span3 tiny'>
            <div class='pricing-table-header-tiny'>
                <h2>" . $row['Question'] . "</h2>


            </div>
                <a id='s'>Show answer</a>
                <div class='dq'>
                    <div class='pricing-table-features'>
                        <p>" . $row['Answer'] . "</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='Dass'>
                        <p id='Dassp'>Answered by:" . $row['Doctor'] . "<p>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
```

```css
.dq {
 display: none;
}

#s:active~ .dq {
display:block;
}

#s {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pure css to achieve this

See how its done !!

You have to make the `a` tag a `link` to make this work on '`:active` state.

```
<a href="" id="s">
```

and write the style for `:focus` state also

The only drawback is that when you click outside the element, the `active` state will gone. In that case, you have to use `jquery`.

```
#s:active~ .dq,  #s:focus~ .dq{
      display: block;
    }
```

```css
.dq {
  display: none;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
 }
#s:active~ .dq,  #s:focus~ .dq{
  display: block;
}
#s {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='span3 tiny'>
  <div class='pricing-table-header-tiny'>
    <h2>" Question : whats is the question ?"</h2>


  </div>
  <a id='s' href="#">Show answer</a>
  <div class='dq'>
    <div class='pricing-table-features'>
      <p>" Hi this is the answer "</p>
    </div>
    <div class='Dass'>
      <p id='Dassp'>Answered by: "Kim"
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that worked  nicely :D perfect.just perfect :D thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery instead:

```
$('#s').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dq').toggleClass('show-answer');
});
```

and then replace your CSS with below:

```
.dq {
    display: none;
}

.dq.show-answer {
display:block;
}

#s {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: i have never played with jquery before.  where do i put the jquery?

Comment: add `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` before `</body>` and then add `<script>/*put the jQuery code mentioned above here*/</script>`

Comment: second script on head too?

Comment: you should put both of them at the end of HTML, just before closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Here Your answer.. make it easy with jquery

```js
$('#s').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dq').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.dq {
 display: none;
}

.dq.active {
display:block;
}

#s {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div><div class="dq">dq</div>

<button id="s" >btn</button>
```

Comment: works for the first column it generates. then just snaps :/

Comment: no no i  mean. the dq comes from an sql table. each dq is a seperate column with a different id each time

Comment: Yes! so where the problem

keep those css class name and button id name same

Comment: add class on button and change in script code "#" to "."